# chart is not readable as the number of X axis values increase

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui

I have a chart with the following CSS, the problem is, number of x-Axis could vary from 10 to 300, when
it's 10, the size is fine in the browser, but when the number of X-axis values increases to 200 or more
, the chart is not readable, I also proved a picture of it, in this case, what is the good way to show it?

```
<div class="chart-wrapper" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 50px;">
    <div class="k-chart" id="topMonth" style="width: 100%; 
        position:relative; touch-action: none;" data-role="chart">
    </div>
</div>
```

[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyGNh.jpg)

Comment: Something is missing here. What library are you using to generate the chart?

Comment: @manassehkatz Kendo UI

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[label.step property](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-xAxis.labels.step)** on the xAxis or categoryAxis to show every nth label.

You could set it dynamically based on the number of x values...

Comment: im looking for a way to scroll it horzontaly an see all th detail,you know how?

Comment: @moris1983, have a look at the pan and zoom demos:  https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/pan-and-zoom  and https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/pan-and-zoom